# PySpark read in a textfile as Dense vectors

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm working with PySpark and trying to load a file of the format below, where each line is a vector of counts

```
[1394, 56692, 0, 10, 22]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2235, 123, 678, 0, 999]
```

And I'm trying to load this into Spark using `sc.textFile(path/to/counts.txt)`. How can I convert each row of the file to be a pyspark ML vector similar to the format below? I'm assuming it's a lambda function but not sure how to convert string to ML Vector.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors as MLVectors
data = [(MLVectors.dense([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0]),), 
(MLVectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),), (MLVectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]
```

Comment: Are the numbers in your text file actually enclosed in `[ ]`, or they are just 5 numbers per row separated by comma?

Comment: Enclosed in [ ]

Comment: Basically, I can put the vectors in any format, for now they were in that format though. The issue I have is that sc.textfile isn't as straightforward as say a readcsv function in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process each line with a `map`

```py
import re
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors as MLVectors
rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/counts.txt")\
    .map(lambda l: MLVectors.dense([int(x) for x in (re.sub("[\[\]]", "", l).split(","))]))
rdd.take(3)

    [DenseVector([1394.0, 56692.0, 0.0, 10.0, 22.0]),
     DenseVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
     DenseVector([2235.0, 123.0, 678.0, 0.0, 999.0])]
```

**Data frames**

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
df = spark.read.csv("path/to/counts.txt")
df = df.select([psf.regexp_replace(c, '[\]\[]', '').cast("float").alias(c) for c in df.columns])
va = VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="vector")
df2 = va.transform(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered the question! I upvoted the solution but unfortunately I need some more reputation before it shows up publicly.

Comment: The reason I asked the question was to create a dataframe similar to df = sqlContext.createdataframe(data, "features") and to do that I needed to add an extra step and use the toDF function, so rdd.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["features"]) and this could then be loaded into other functions.

Comment: if you intend to convert it to dataframe you should consider loading it like a csv and using `vectorAssembler`. See my updateed answer

Comment: I hope this helped! don't forget to mark your question as solved :)

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut, appreciate that